# How to declare predicates over arbitrary sized bit bit vectors in z3?

Tags: z3

I encountered a problem while trying to define some rules over bit vectors in z3. If I try to solve the following file with z3

```lisp
(declare-rel FunnyFun ((_ BitVec 64)))
(declare-var A (_ BitVec 64))
(declare-var B (_ BitVec 64))
(rule (=> (= B (bvadd A #x0000000000000001))
    (FunnyFun B)))

(declare-rel q1 ())

(rule (=> (FunnyFun #x0000000000000001) q1))

(query q1)
```

I get the error

```lisp
(error "query failed: Rule contains infinite sorts in rule <null>:
FunnyFun(#0) :- 
 (= (:var 0) (bvadd (:var 1) #x0000000000000001)).
")
```

Funnily enough z3 instantly gives the expected result (sat) when using smaller bit widths:

```lisp
(declare-rel FunnyFun ((_ BitVec 60)))
(declare-var A (_ BitVec 60))
(declare-var B (_ BitVec 60))
(rule (=> (= B (bvadd A #x000000000000001))
    (FunnyFun B)))

(declare-rel q1 ())

(rule (=> (FunnyFun #x000000000000001) q1))

(query q1)
```

Is this a bug or am I missing some constraints (I assumed BitVec can have an arbitrary bit width)?

I tried different z3 version (`4.6.0`, `4.8.3` and `4.8.5`) and all of them showed this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This limitation is by design. See here: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/1698